# I cannot init a repository on my remote server

Tags: git, repository, remote-server

I''m new to git and I tried to initialize a git repository on my remote server, by doing this

```
git init --bare repo.git
```

But it turns the result

```
-bash: git: command not found
```

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download and install git on the remote computer: http://git-scm.com/download